# How to properly obtain the user's phone number during the account linking?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-authentication

We are building the Google Action with Dialogflow integration. We've started to add the authentication procedure and we chose the Google Sign-In & OAuth approach. We decided so because we have the 3rd party service, which has its own users. Also, there should be the possibility to create new users. The new user could be created based on the JWT token payload received from Google. The payload has the following structure (taken from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?oauth=code):

```
{
  "sub": 1234567890,        // The unique ID of the user's Google Account
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",        // The assertion's issuer
  "aud": "123-abc.apps.googleusercontent.com", // Your server's client ID
  "iat": 233366400,         // Unix timestamp of the assertion's creation time
  "exp": 233370000,         // Unix timestamp of the assertion's expiration time
  "name": "Jan Jansen",
  "given_name": "Jan",
  "family_name": "Jansen",
  "email": "jan@gmail.com", // If present, the user's email address
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Hence, what we can get from the above object is `email`, `firstName` and `lastName`. But for us is very important to get the phone number of the user. Is it possible to obtain the phone number or the only solution is to ask the user about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the claims that the token contains on the 3rd party service to include the phone of the user.

And for the possibility of creating new users, that's a whole new intent, where you can include a question for the user's phone.

Comment: Not sure that Google has this as an oauth field.

Comment: If the OP has control over the OAuth system, there should be something to add additional fields. He points out that he is using a 3rd party service so I assumed he is not using Google for OAuth?